# Android - activities in the background

Tags: android

I have a pretty annoying problem, which I have been trying to solve for 2 days now...

So, I have activity A and activity B. You can navigate from A to B. When I navigate to activity B, I create a timer that I want to run in the background and just measure the time since I pressed a button that is located in activity B. However, when I go back to activity A and try to navigate to B again, I find it reset back to the original state, despite the fact that I have not destroyed it. Is there any way to have it working in the background or not reset itself when I navigate back to it?

Comment: You can create an Application class instance which will be alive through out the application life cycle and it is singleton and set the timer there when you press button in Activity B. Because Application instance is singleton and present through out the app life cycle its properties are not garbage collected :) Not happy with Application class instance (by the way thats the cleanest way to write code ) use sharePreferrence editor save current time stamp when u tap button in activity B when you come back calculate the difference :) Wanna know how to write Application instance?? Lemme know

Comment: I have an Application class instance but I had severe problems having a timer working there:
`long startTime = 0;
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable() -> {
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
`
At this point, I get an error - variable startTime is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. But if I make it final, I cannot overwrite it. This problem does not happen when I do it in an Activity for some reason...

Comment: What kind of issue??

Comment: Please post your relevant codes and analysis on the issue as well.
See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question...

Comment: This isn't a issue with application class instance correct :D This problem will be there no matter whereever you write code :)

Comment: I cannot put all the code up for confidentiality reasons...

Comment: No, if I put the exact same code in the Activity it works fine.

Comment: Hmmmm Interesting...

Comment: How about this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388932/how-to-pass-variables-from-the-thread-to-the-outside-environment-in-android

Comment: Hey I updated and posted the code which works absolutely fine :) tested on my device and it is working fine :) Try it n lemme know its working or not for u :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted you cant have a property in Activity B and expect it to survive through out the application life cycle. As I mentioned in my comments you need Application class instance to maintain such properties. So I providing the code for the same. I did not face any issue which you mentined in comment please check this and lemme know if any issue :)

```
package com.example.sandeepbhandari.myapplication;
import android.app.Application;

/**
 * Created by sandeepbhandari on 3/3/16.
 */
    public class AppService extends Application{
    private static AppService sInstance;
    long timeElapsed = 0;
    Timer t;
    TimerTask task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        t = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                timeElapsed ++;
            }
        };
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
    }


    public void stopTimer(){
        if(t != null) {
            t.cancel();
        }
    }

    public static AppService getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

In order to use this application class you need to update your manifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:name=".AppService"
```

At any point if you want to start timer (In your case onClickListener of button in Activity B) simply call

```
AppService service = AppService.getInstance();
service.startTimer();
```

And to stop simply call

```
AppService service = AppService.getInstance();
service. stopTimer();
```

And whenever you want to see the time elapsed simply say `Log.d("sandeep", "" + service.timeElapsed);`

I din find any issue in this :o you still have issue?? lemme know :)

Comment: Ah, I see. So I am allowed to use multiple Applications within my app right?